# Returning multiple possible types from function - C++

Tags: c++, oop

I am making an input system for my application. I currently have an InputManager class that stores a list of InputAction instances. I want to be able to have a function on InputManager that gets some value from any of its InputAction. The problem is that I want to make children of InputAction that return different types of values. For instance for a key press I want the KeyInputAction to return a boolean and the MouseMoveInputAction should return a float vector. Is this possible or is it bad design?

```
    template <class T>
    class InputAction
    {
    public:
        InputAction(std::string name);
        ~InputAction();
    
        template <class T>
        virtual T GetValue();
    protected:
        std::string m_Name;
    };
    
    class InputManager
    {
    public: 
        InputManager();
        ~InputManager();
    
        template <typename T>
        T GetValue(std::string actionName);
    
    private: 
        std::hash_map<std::string, InputAction*> m_InputActionMap;
    };

    template <typename T>
    T InputManager::GetValue(std::string actionName)
    {
        InputAction* action = m_InputActionMap.at(actionName);
        auto value = action->GetValue();
        return value;
    }
```

Comment: If you can limit the possibilities to a reasonable number returning `std::variant`is an option, but I don't like this idea. Take a look at the idea behind the Visitor pattern instead. See if passing in an object that `InputManager` can operate on instead of trying to get an object out makes sense.

Comment: It's perfectly possible, and pretty much what Object Oriented Programming is all about. One simple way to construct things is so that each of your InputActions returns an enumerated value that describes what type of action it is so that anyone looking at the action can determine what to do with it.  This would allow you to avoid having to use templates at all and you could, if you liked, build accessors that only get you the input types you were interested in.